# Multiply kg and grams unit with price per kg

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I'm currently have a task when I have to calculate the values for the cost of supplies which I have to multiply priceperweight with weight. But in weight there's also kg and grams. When I multiply it, it gives the results like $3000 for 500 grams of Spinach. Here's my scheme. Please help. All help would be appreciated :D Here's my code! Thank you so much

```
select PricePerWeight * Weight from Supplies;
```

[image: Supplies]

Comment: It would be more efficient to use the same units throughout

Answer (score 0):

Normalize the weight to grams or Kg (I'll use grams) using `CASE x WHEN y`:

```
SELECT
    s.*,
    CASE s.metric
        WHEN 'Kilos' THEN ( s.weight * 1000 )
        WHEN 'grams' THEN ( s.weight *    1 ) ELSE NULL
    END AS weightInGrams
FROM
    supplies AS s
```

Then adding [additional units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_humorous_units_of_measurement) is straightforward:

```
SELECT
    s.*,
    CASE s.metric
        WHEN 'tonnes'  THEN ( s.weight * 1000 * 1000 )
        WHEN 'Kilos'   THEN ( s.weight * 1000 )
        WHEN 'grams'   THEN ( s.weight *    1 )
        WHEN 'jupiter' THEN ( s.weight * 1.9 * POW( 10, 27 ) * 1000 )
        WHEN 'lbs'     THEN ( s.weight * 453.592 ) ELSE NULL
    END AS weightInGrams
FROM
    supplies AS s
```

Assuming you're using ISO-compliant SQL, you'll need to use an outer-query or a CTE to then multiply by `pricePerWeight`, which I assume is in Kg:

Note that the queries below still use grams as the base unit of mass to avoid problems caused by integer division (as SQL does not make it easy to make sure numeric literals are processed as floats or decimals instead of integers, as integer division truncates rather than rounds).

The final value is the `thePrice` column in the queries below:

#### Option 1: Using an outer-query:

```
SELECT
    s2.*,
    ( s2.pricePerWeight * s2.weightInGrams ) / 1000.00 AS thePrice
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            s.*,
            CASE s.metric
                WHEN 'tonnes'  THEN ( s.weight * 1000 * 1000 )
                WHEN 'Kilos'   THEN ( s.weight * 1000 )
                WHEN 'grams'   THEN ( s.weight *    1 )
                WHEN 'jupiter' THEN ( s.weight * 1.9 * POW( 10, 27 ) * 1000 )
                WHEN 'lbs'     THEN ( s.weight * 453.592 ) ELSE NULL
            END AS weightInGrams
        FROM
            supplies AS s
    )
```

#### Option 2: Using a CTE:

```
WITH s2 AS (
    SELECT
        s.*,
        CASE s.metric
            WHEN 'tonnes'  THEN ( s.weight * 1000 * 1000 )
            WHEN 'Kilos'   THEN ( s.weight * 1000 )
            WHEN 'grams'   THEN ( s.weight *    1 )
            WHEN 'jupiter' THEN ( s.weight * 1.9 * POW( 10, 27 ) * 1000 )
            WHEN 'lbs'     THEN ( s.weight * 453.592 ) ELSE NULL
        END AS weightInGrams
    FROM
        supplies AS s
)
SELECT
    s2.*,
    ( s2.pricePerWeight * s2.weightInGrams ) / 1000.00 AS thePrice
FROM
    s2
```

Comment: try this -> select PricePerWeight * (CASE s.metric WHEN 'Kilos' THEN ( s.weight * 1000 )WHEN 'grams' THEN (s.weight*1 ) ELSE 0 END)  from supplies as s;

Comment: @pisi1001 I don’t have a MySQL instance at-hand to test it on. What happens?

Comment: @Dai try [link](https://www.db-fiddle.com) https://www.db-fiddle.com it is useful